# Jquery addRow and autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a table I would like to use autocomplete on a column. 
(medSearch is the class set for this column)

I use the Jquery's autocomplete code

```
autocomp_opt={
    source: function(request,response){
        var myTable = [];        
        var searchStr = $(".medSearch").val();

        if (searchStr.length>2)
        {        
            alert(searchStr);                    
            var soapEnv = "... searchStr.....";

            $.ajax(
            {            
                .............
```

Then I use Cloud Gen's addRow javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".addRow").btnAddRow(function(row){row.find(".medSearch").autocomplete(autocomp_opt)});
    $(".delRow").btnDelRow();
    $(".medSearch").autocomplete(autocomp_opt); //end autocomplete

}); //end document. ready
```

However, the autocomplete does not work properly with newly added row's column.

The user's input in this new row's column is not taken for the autocomplete query.

It always takes the first row's column content as the input.

I think it's because the jQuery always takes the first item which has class '.medSearch'. Then it does not take the current row's user input.

I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you for your help in advance!

My further question:
Actually, this my further question (it is too long for a comment)

I have two more columns with class identifier medCode and medDin, they need to be populated by the autocomplete result:

```
                    success: function(xml){

                    //alert($(xml).text());
                    //traverse the xml
                    var xmlItem = $(xml).find("*").eq(0);

                    //alert($(xmlItem)[0].nodeName);

                    var xmlMedItemArr = $(xmlItem).children().children().children();

                    //alert("Phyiscian Items: "+$(xmlPhyItemArr).length);           


                    // go through each of them
                    $(xmlMedItemArr).each(function()
                    {
                            //do what? get each text
                            var childList = $(this).children();

                            myTable.push({
                                label: $(childList[0]).text() + " - " + $(childList[2]).text(),
                                value: $(childList[0]).text(),
                                din: $(childList[2]).text(),
                                code: $(childList[1]).text()
                            });

                    });

        select: function(event,ui) {
            $(".medCode").val(ui.item.code);
            $(".medDin").val(ui.item.din);
        },
```

But as the previous problem, after I select an item from the list of autocomplete result, then the two columns of all rows will be set to the same value.

How can this be done correctly?

Thank you very much for your help!

Here is the html for the table part. (we use ebase xi as the platform. It is a drag and drop web development tool. It will generate the html and some of the script automatically. You will see in the html code)

```
<!----><div class="CTID-1182-_ eb-1182-panel ">  
<!---->Current Medications</div>
<!----><table class="CTID-1156-_ eb-1156-tableControl " summary="">
<tr>
<td>
<table class="eb-1156-tableNavRow " style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="99%">
<span class="eb-1156-tableNavRowInfo " style="padding-left:10px;">Displaying 1...1 of 1 records</span></td>
<td width="1%" align="right">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="eb-1156-tableContent " summary="" title="">
<colgroup>
<col style="width:20%;"><col style="width:4%;"><col style="width:4%;"><col style="width:7%;"><col style="width:7%;"><col style="width:7%;"><col style="width:7%;"><col style="width:11%;"><col style="width:11%;"></colgroup>
<tr>
<th id="CTID-1156-_-C-1164" class="eb-1156-tableColumnHeader eb-1164-tableColumnHeader ">
Medicine Name</th>
<th id="CTID-1156-_-C-1168" class="eb-1156-tableColumnHeader eb-1168-tableColumnHeader ">
Med code</th>
<th id="CTID-1156-_-C-1170" class="eb-1156-tableColumnHeader eb-1170-tableColumnHeader ">
Med drug identification number</th>
<th id="CTID-1156-_-C-1175" class="eb-1156-tableColumnHeader eb-1175-tableColumnHeader ">
Dosage</th>
<th id="CTID-1156-_-C-1177" class="eb-1156-tableColumnHeader eb-1177-tableColumnHeader ">
Unit</th>
<th id="CTID-1156-_-C-1179" class="eb-1156-tableColumnHeader eb-1179-tableColumnHeader ">
Frequency</th>
<th id="CTID-1156-_-C-1181" class="eb-1156-tableColumnHeader eb-1181-tableColumnHeader ">
Unit</th>
<th id="CTID-1156-_-C-1200" class="eb-1156-tableColumnHeader eb-1200-tableColumnHeader ">
</th>
<th id="CTID-1156-_-C-1196" class="eb-1156-tableColumnHeader eb-1196-tableColumnHeader ">
</th>
</tr>
<tr class="CTID-1156-_-R-0 eb-1156-tableRow eb-1156-tableRow ">
<td class="eb-1156-tableContentCell eb-1164-tableColumn " headers="CTID-1156-_-C-1164"><div class="eb-1164-Editor " style="display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline;">
<input id="CTID-1164-_-C-0" class="CTID-1164-_-C-0 eb-1156-tableContentData eb-1164-EditorInput medSearch" type="text" name="CTRL:1164:_:C:0" size="50" maxlength="128" title="Medicine Name"></div>
</td>
<td class="eb-1156-tableContentCell eb-1168-tableColumn " headers="CTID-1156-_-C-1168"><div class="eb-1168-Editor " style="display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline;">
<input id="CTID-1168-_-C-0" class="CTID-1168-_-C-0 eb-1156-tableContentData eb-1168-EditorInput medCode" type="text" name="CTRL:1168:_:C:0" size="5" maxlength="32" title="Med code"></div>
</td>
<td class="eb-1156-tableContentCell eb-1170-tableColumn " headers="CTID-1156-_-C-1170"><div class="eb-1170-Editor " style="display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline;">
<input id="CTID-1170-_-C-0" class="CTID-1170-_-C-0 eb-1156-tableContentData eb-1170-EditorInput medDin" type="text" name="CTRL:1170:_:C:0" size="5" maxlength="64" title="Med drug identification number"></div>
</td>
<td class="eb-1156-tableContentCell eb-1175-tableColumn " headers="CTID-1156-_-C-1175"><div class="eb-1175-Editor " style="display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline;">
<input id="CTID-1175-_-C-0" class="CTID-1175-_-C-0 eb-1156-tableContentData eb-1175-EditorInput " type="text" name="CTRL:1175:_:C:0" size="5" maxlength="10" title="Dosage"></div>
</td>
<td class="eb-1156-tableContentCell eb-1177-tableColumn " headers="CTID-1156-_-C-1177"><div class="eb-1177-Editor " style="display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline;">
<select id="CTID-1177-_-C-0" class="CTID-1177-_-C-0 eb-1156-tableContentData eb-1177-EditorInput " name="CTRL:1177:_:C:0" title="Unit"><option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option><option value="109">mg</option><option value="110">ml</option></select></div>
</td>
<td class="eb-1156-tableContentCell eb-1179-tableColumn " headers="CTID-1156-_-C-1179"><div class="eb-1179-Editor " style="display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline;">
<input id="CTID-1179-_-C-0" class="CTID-1179-_-C-0 eb-1156-tableContentData eb-1179-EditorInput " type="text" name="CTRL:1179:_:C:0" size="5" maxlength="64" title="Frequency"></div>
</td>
<td class="eb-1156-tableContentCell eb-1181-tableColumn " headers="CTID-1156-_-C-1181"><div class="eb-1181-Editor " style="display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline;">
<select id="CTID-1181-_-C-0" class="CTID-1181-_-C-0 eb-1156-tableContentData eb-1181-EditorInput " name="CTRL:1181:_:C:0" title="Unit"><option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option><option value="112">per day</option><option value="113">per 4 hours</option></select></div>
</td>
<td class="eb-1156-tableContentCell eb-1200-tableColumn " headers="CTID-1156-_-C-1200"><input class="CTID-1200-_-C-0 eb-1200-Button addRow" type="submit" name="CTRL:1200:_:D:0" value="Add" title=""></td>
<td class="eb-1156-tableContentCell eb-1196-tableColumn " headers="CTID-1156-_-C-1196"><img class="eb-1196-Image delRow" src="shared/uohi/images/delete_icon.gif" alt="" title="">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share the code for btnAddRow() and btnDelRow()?  I don't quite understand what you are doing with those.

Comment: Where is `childList` defined?

Comment: I added that part of code to my question. I think the problem may still related to the class identifier for my columns .medCode and .medDin. Then when set values, the columns with these class identifier in all rows are set with the same value.

Comment: I see. Can you show a snippet of the HTML you're working with? You need to find those elements relative to the autocomplete you're working with.

Comment: I have put the html code for the table part to my question area. they are auto generated code by the dev tool we use ebase xi (drag and drop)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var searchStr = request.term;
```

instead of what you currently have.

The existing code:

```
var searchStr = $(".medSearch").val();
```

Reads the value of the *first* element that meets the selector `.medSearch`

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you very much. I changed to request.term. It works now!

Comment: I have one more further question: I have two more fi

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry, I am new to this forum. I haven't figured out how to correctly use all the functions of the thread yet. Could you take a look my further question it is in the second answer for this question.

Comment: @XiaoliRen: That's ok-- you can edit your question to include the new information (that's the proper way) and delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help.
I have the correct value now by using the following code:

```
            $(this).closest('tr').find(".medCode").val(ui.item.code);
            $(this).closest('tr').find(".medDin").val(ui.item.din);
```

Thanks,
Xiaoli